# Big O - Don't understand time complexity for these algorithms?

Tags: java, algorithm, time, complexity-theory

I am learning how to do time complexity in school and the professor uploaded some examples. For the first example below, the answer is supposed to be O(n^3) but I do not understand how.

```
public static int fragment1 (int n)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n*n; i++) 
       for (int j = 0; j*j < i; j++) sum++;
    return sum;
} // end fragment1
```

When I attempt the problem I look at the first for loop and see that it runs n^2 times, then the inner for loop is also n^2. When added up I get O(n^4).

```
public static int fragment5 (int n) 
{
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i=0; i < n*n*n; i++)
    {
        if(i%(n*n) == 0) {
            for(int j=i*i; j > 0; j--)
                sum++;
        } // if
        else
        {
            for(int k=0; k < i: k++)
                sum++;
        } // else
    } // outer loop
}
```

For the problem above, the answer should be O(n^7). When I attempted it I got: first for loop runs n^3 times, inner for loop n^3*n^3 = n^6, and the for loop inside the else statement I get n with my final answer being O(n^10). Can someone give me tips on the above problem? I feel clueless when it comes to this one and I have been getting the other problems right so far.

Comment: For the first example, are n and j somehow related? Is there additional information to the problem?  The outer loop runs n^2 times but inner loop runs j^2 times.  Unless n == j, you cant say they combine to n^4.

Comment: These are not serious algorithms - these are just tricks to teach you about complexity, which you will need to learn for yourself. I'm sure that there is a teaching assistant who can help you. Hint for example 1, you say "then the inner for loop is also n^2" - wrong. Have a good look at what the loop actually says. It doesn't say `j < i`, it says `j * j < i`.

Comment: A bigger hints for Q1:  Try integration x^(1/2)  from x = 1 to n^2

For Q2: The worst case is at the `if` block, and try to figure out how many times will the `j` loop happens by thinking how many times the `if` condition will be true

Comment: You can verify your answer by running the code with various values of n and plotting that against the final value of sum.  Try n = 10, 20, 30, 40

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the basic assumptions when calculating BigO is to **drop non dominant terms**.

Using the first example,

- Outer Loop has order O(n^2)
- Inner Loop has order O(n^3)

  - The inner loop independently runs for 'n' times but because it is nested, it will run for 'n * (n^2)
    '

So, the BigO is of the form O((n^2) + (n^3)) which would suffice to O(n^3).

You can try using the same technique for the second problem. 
If you still have some confusion, have a look at the following video:
[Big O Notation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v4cd1O4zkGw&list=PLX6IKgS15Ue02WDPRCmYKuZicQHit9kFt&index=7)

Comment: Very helpful, I appreciate it